# Why don't my buttons reference the audio link I want them to?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I'm trying to make a web application where one of the parts is a feature where you can play/pause different songs with a mouse click. The problem is that if there are multiple songs on a page, all of the play/pause buttons only apply to one song (the last song added). How do I fix it so that each of the play/pause buttons correspond to a specific song? I've already tried it with audio id, but it's not working. Here is the HTML/JS for the part of my code:

```
   {% for song, posts in posts_dict.items() %}

    <div>
        <audio id="{{ song.song_uri[14:] }}" src="{{ song.song_preview }}">
        </audio>
        <button onclick="play()" type="button">Play Song</button>
        <button onclick="pause()" type="button">Pause Song</button>
        <img src="{{ song.album_picture }}" alt="Album Picture">
        <script>
        function play() {
            var audio = document.getElementById("{{ song.song_uri[14:] }}");
            audio.play();
        }
        function pause() {
            var audio = document.getElementById("{{ song.song_uri[14:] }}");
            audio.pause();
        }
        </script>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

And here is the Javascript Console for the code. All of the references seem to be in order (i.e. the buttons are mapped to the correct audio links) so I don't understand why it defaults to the last song added.
[Javascript Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RA8KX.png)

Comment: Good starting point would be a chrome debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the script tag outside of for loop and in play and pause pause pass the ID of the audio

```
{% for song, posts in posts_dict.items() %}

    <div>
        <audio id="{{ song.song_uri[14:] }}" src="{{ song.song_preview }}">
        </audio>
        <button onclick="play({{ song.song_uri[14:] }})" type="button">Play Song</button>
        <button onclick="pause({{ song.song_uri[14:] }})" type="button">Pause Song</button>
        <img src="{{ song.album_picture }}" alt="Album Picture">
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

**id you added in for loop**

```
  <script>
        function play(id) {
            var audio = document.getElementById(id);
            audio.play();
        }
        function pause(id) {
            var audio = document.getElementById(id);
            audio.pause();
        }
        </script>
```